# How do I apply a patch for IBM Lotus Sametime Connect 8.0.2?

Tags: lotus-notes, instant-messaging, sametime

I am packaging Sametime client 8.0.2 for deployment. I have received the binaries from our Notes Admins. They have also given me the following zip file along with original installation:  "sametime.patches.update.site.20090317-0613.zip"

This file contains two folders "features" and "plugins" and "site.xml" file. The folders contain a bunch of *.jar files.

Can any help me figure out how to apply this patch to an installation? There don't seem to be any instructions with the original install or the patch. I've already asked my Admins for more info, but was wondering if anyone here has experience with it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the procedure in case anyone is wondering:

1. Log into Sametime
2. Select Tools -> Plug-ins > Install Plugins...
3. In the update manager wizard, select "Search for New Features To Install"
4. Select "Add Zip/Jar" button.
5. Navigate to the location  "sametime.patches.update.site.20090317-0613.zip"
6. Click OK to accept the site and then click Finish to proceed.
7. In the Select Features to Install box, check all features
8. Click Next, complete the license page and select Finish
9. Select "Install" on the next page
10. After the feature is installed you should be prompted to restart. Select OK